# Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check

Tags: python

I have .zip file which contain csv data. I am reading .zip file using

```
<input type = "file" name = "select_file"/>
```

I want to decompress that .zip file and read csv data.

```
file_data = self.request.get('select_file')
file_str = zlib.decompress(file_data)  

#file_data_list = file_str.split('\n')
#file_Reader = csv.reader(file_data_list,quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE )
```

I am expecting csv data in file_str but I am getting error.

```
error :: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check
```

What I have to use?

Comment: it looks like damaged zip file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making a [zipfile.ZipFile](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html?highlight=zipfile#zipfile-objects) object instead -- as the first argument, you need an open file-like object, so first make one out of your `file_data` bytes with [cStringIO](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html?highlight=cstringio#module-cStringIO).